# Jacoco Code coverage with multiple modules, gradle configuration

Tags: java, android, gradle, jacoco

Consider a project with multiple subprojects :

- `presentation` (Android application) type android
- `domain` (POJO) type java
- `data` (Android module) type android

I would like to check the code coverage of my instrumentation tests for the whole project.

Currently I have just added the following to `build.gradle` in `presentation`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled = true
    }
}
```

By running `gradle createDebugCoverageReport` I get a report with only the classes in `presentation`

What do I have to change to display a report with every class of the whole project when only running instrumentation tests? (no unit tests)

Comment: Hi, Did you get any success in it.

Comment: Actually no. It was too time consuming I gave up :/